# Numerical algorithm for largest Eigenvalue problem

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I am dealing with calculating an eigenvalue problem for differential operator  of order 4:
$$
\alpha \cdot\Delta^2 u+\Delta u-\Delta(u\cdot u_p(x))=\lambda u
$$
where 
$\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$, $\Delta$ is Laplacian, $u_p$ is  given (numerical) solution and $\Delta^2$ is $\Delta \Delta$ .

Is there any "best" known algorithm for computing the largest eigenvalue for large sparse matrices?

Thank you